# How to pass Json collection object to mvc controller action method

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I am creating one Json array object and trying to pass it in MVC controller action method but i am getting null paramerter; as per my knowledge json only maps .net primitive datatypes.... so it assign null value.

Note: when i have look at request object i found that there are three parameter of created array. But how to get that value as parameter of function?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom model binder which will take the json value and construct a model object which can be passed into your action.

Another option is to use a different value binder. See [Phil Haack's site](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx) for an example.

Comment: same issue i am facing. did you succeeded ? please guide me. what you have done for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to create custom model class for each time you call an action, then you can use my solution here

[Pass JSON Object To MVC Controller as an Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069171/pass-json-object-to-mvc-controller-as-an-argument/12085898#12085898)