# Pass JSON Object To MVC Controller as an Argument

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jsonresult

I have the following arbitrary JSON object(The field names may be changed).

```
  {
    firstname: "Ted",
    lastname: "Smith",
    age: 34,
    married : true
  }
```

-

```
public JsonResult GetData(??????????){
.
.
.
}
```

I know that I can define a class just like the JSON object with the same field names as the argument, But I would like my controller to accept arbitrary JSON object with different field names.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022958/passing-dynamic-json-object-to-c-sharp-mvc-controller) question

Comment: Vadim, I knew this... The problem is that FormCollection doesn't accept the JSON...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to pass custom JSON object to MVC action then you can use this solution, it works like a charm.

```
    public string GetData()
    {
        // InputStream contains the JSON object you've sent
        String jsonString = new StreamReader(this.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

        // Deserialize it to a dictionary
        var dic = 
          Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<String, dynamic>>(jsonString);

        string result = "";

        result += dic["firstname"] + dic["lastname"];

        // You can even cast your object to their original type because of 'dynamic' keyword
        result += ", Age: " + (int)dic["age"];

        if ((bool)dic["married"])
            result += ", Married";


        return result;
    }
```

The real benefit of this solution is that you don't require to define a new class for each combination of arguments and beside that, you can cast your objects to their original types easily.

**UPDATED**

Now, you can even merge your GET and POST action methods since your post method doesn't have any argument any more just like this :

```
 public ActionResult GetData()
 {
    // GET method
    if (Request.HttpMethod.ToString().Equals("GET"))
        return View();

    // POST method 
    .
    .
    .

    var dic = GetDic(Request);
    .
    .
    String result = dic["fname"];

    return Content(result);
 }
```

and you can use a helper method like this to facilitate your job

```
public static Dictionary<string, dynamic> GetDic(HttpRequestBase request)
{
    String jsonString = new StreamReader(request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(jsonString);
}
```

Comment: Nice solution to avoid strongly typing all comms between client & server.

Answer (score 1):

Have a ViewModel with the same signature and use that as the argument type.Model binding will work then

```
public class Customer
{
  public string firstname { set;get;}
  public string lastname { set;get;}
  public int age{ set;get;} 
  public string location{ set;get;}
   //other relevant proeprties also
}
```

And your Action method will look like

```
public JsonResult GetData(Customer customer)
{
  //check customer object properties now.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this in MVC 4

```
public JsonResult GetJson(Dictionary<string,string> param)
{
    //do work
}
```