# Parse JSON object in c# passed through jquery Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I know this is one of the most commonly asked questions in ASP.net but my scenario is a bit different.

I have a json object which I am converting to a string and passing it to web method via jquery ajax.

```
function Save() {
            var content = $('#radGridSMT_ctl00 tr').not('#radGridSMT_ctl00 thead tr');
            var header = $('#radGridSMT_ctl00_Header thead tr');
            var result = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < content.length - 1; i++) {
                item = {}
                var headerName;
                item[header[0].children[0].textContent] = content[i].children[0].textContent;
                item[header[0].children[1].textContent] = content[i].children[1].textContent;
                item[header[0].children[2].textContent] = content[i].children[2].textContent;
                item[header[0].children[3].textContent] = content[i].children[3].textContent;
                item[header[0].children[4].textContent] = content[i].children[4].textContent;
                item[header[0].children[5].textContent] = content[i].children[5].textContent;
                item[header[0].children[6].textContent] = content[i].children[6].textContent;
                item[header[0].children[7].textContent] = content[i].children[7].textContent;
                item[header[0].children[8].textContent] = content[i].children[8].textContent;
                item[header[0].children[9].textContent] = content[i].children[9].textContent;
                item[header[0].children[10].textContent] = content[i].children[10].textContent;
                item[header[0].children[11].textContent] = content[i].children[11].textContent;
                item[header[0].children[12].textContent] = content[i].children[12].textContent;
                result.push(item);
            }
            result = JSON.stringify({ data: result });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "SMTRequiredHour.aspx/SaveData",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: result,
                success: function (response) {

                },
                failure: function (response) {

                }
            });
        }
```

Now when I receive it in web method is comes in the form of an object.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void SaveData(object data)
    {
        CreateDatatable(data);
        var d = initialData;
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
    }
```

The JsonConvert.DeserializeObject takes a string not an object and that's the problem. I am unable to convert JSON object to string.

I can't create strong type object because the columns in the json object are generate dynamically and may not be same every time.

How to parse JSON object to a string so that I can deserialize it.

Comment: method `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String)` is to Deserializes the JSON to a .NET object ? You already have the `object data`, am i right?

Comment: Did you try use `string data` instead of `object data`? So you will be able deserialize your JSON

Comment: Yes I tried accepting the JSON string as a string in web method but then the ajax call doesn't hit the web method.

Comment: @jacky: Yes, i have the data but in the form of object. I need to it in the form of string so that i can pass it to DeserializeObject(string).

Comment: @Satindersingh: I explicitly said that I can't create strong type objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass JSON Object To MVC Controller as an Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069171/pass-json-object-to-mvc-controller-as-an-argument)

Comment: @user728630 try to remove `contentType` and `dataType` from your ajax call and change `object data` to `string data`

Comment: in order to convert object to json, you can try Newtonsoft NuGet package. (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). By the way, if your web method is a void method, I dont think there is anything return back to client after web method has been called.

Comment: @feeper: I tried that just now and web method doesn't get called.

Comment: @ChinhPhan: That worked ! Lol I was using Newtonsoft already but did not know that I should serialize it first. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Great. you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

What does `data.ToString()` return?

If it doesn't solve it, try to send it as text from the JavaScript side. You could use `data: JSON.stringify(result),` And then set the data type to string in the web method.

Comment: `data.ToString()` will return `"System.Object"`

Comment: If I set data type to string in web method then ajax call doesn't reach to the web method.

Comment: Then keep it as object, but send as string from JavaScript, and use ToString() og casting to convert to string in WebMethod.

Comment: @Tejre: I did that in quick watch and it gave me the value "System.Object[]". I don't know what to do with this.